# Invalid Cast Exception when filling datatable wth table adaptor

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using VB.NET 2010 (Visual Basic 2010 Express) on a WPF-based project. I am also using the SQL Server Express built-in to Visual Basic 2010 express.

I have just about finished refining my code for hooking up my wpf-based form to an existing SQL database (agentroster.sdf). I have a global data source (AGENT_ROSTER) connected to this database. Connections are confirmed to work properly.

This is the first part of the code I'm using, irrelevant code omitted,

```
Dim table_adaptor As New AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptors.AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptor
Dim roster_table As New DataTable("roster_table")
Dim rowposition As Integer

Private Sub ROSTER_Loaded...
   table_adaptor.Fill(roster_table)
End Sub
```

I am getting the following errors:
(In Immediate Window)

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occured in VBP-WORD4WORD.exe

(In Message, pointing to the line: "table_adaptor.Fill(roster_table)')

> InvalidCastException was unhandled
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'AGENT_ROSTERDataTable'.

What am I doing wrong, and furthermore, how do I fill roster_table with table_adaptor (or alternate method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your strongly typed DataSet is called "AGENT_ROSTER":

```
Dim table_adaptor As New AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptors.AGENT_ROSTERTableAdaptor
Dim roster_table As New AGENT_ROSTER.roster_table
table_adaptor.Fill(roster_table)
```

Have a look at [Efficient Coding With Strongly Typed DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163877.aspx).